# Formatting a string to date-like format

Tags: c++, format

I have a class that takes a string as a parameter. I need to print out the date in the format of `MM/DD/YYYY`. The input could be exmaple: 03242014 or 3242014.

I thought using the `SubString()` function would work but I am not sure how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but using `substr` a solution for your problem could look like this:

```
//formatDate(date)
//IN: str or int of form: 01234567 or 1234567
//OUT: str of form: 23/01/4567
string formatDate(const string& date)
{
    string ret = date;
    if(date.length() == 8)
    {
        ret = date.substr(0,2) + '/' +
                date.substr(2,2) + '/' +
                date.substr(4);
    }
    else if(date.length() == 7)
    {
        ret = '0' + date.substr(0,1) + '/' +
                date.substr(1,2) + '/' +
                date.substr(3);
    }
    return ret;
};
string formatDate(int i) 
{
    return formatDate(to_string(i));
}
```

Note that the following will work:

```
cout << formatDate("03242014") <<'\n'
     << formatDate("3242014") <<'\n'
     << formatDate(3242014) <<'\n';
```

while:

```
cout << formatDate(03242014) <<'\n'
```

will not as `03242014` denotes an [octal number](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/hex/).